# How to fix toilet jets clogged with chlorine tablet chunks

Tags: toilet, cleaning, clog, chemicals, chlorine

The flush on my toilet is weak.  It went from strong to weak overnight.  It flushes fine if I dump in extra water.  I watched and the flapper does stay open until the reservoir is adequately empty.  I researched and determined the jets must be clogged.  This model toilet does not have a large jet at the bottom, but it does have large jets under the lip at the front of the bowl.  I used a mirror and I can see the blockage.  It's a crumbled chlorine tablet that made it past the flapper.  I used a hanger, but can't pin the pieces well enough to crush them.  I assume it will continue to dissolve and someday eventually come out in a flush.  Any ideas on how to make it dissolve faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleach and chlorine can get nasty very fast if you try to put other chemicals in the tank to help the tablet dissolve.  I think the safest bet is to fill your tank with warm water and use that for several flushes.  Don't use water that is too hot because that could start to cause issues with the wax seal on the toilet if that gets too warm.  Just warm, touchable water should help dissolve it much faster than normal cold tank water.

Comment: Perhaps I can connect a hose from the sink and provide a continual flow of hot water until it dissolves.  Where is the wax seal that I need to avoid?

Comment: @Kirkland, the wax seal is at the base of the toilet.  It's what connects the toilet to the drain pipe in the floor, so it's unavoidable, but I think it would take pretty hot water over a long period to affect it.  If you're going to use the hose, keep the water warm rather than full-hot.